# Is this what rnorm(x) does if x is a vector, and how could I have found out faster?

Tags: r

I’m looking for R resources, and I started looking at “An Introduction to R” [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html) at r-project.org. I did and got stumped immediately.

I think I've figured out what’s going on, and my question is basically

- **Are there resources to help me figure out something like this more
  easily?**

The preface of the Introduction to R suggests starting with the introductory session in Appendix A, and right at the start is this code and remark.

```
x <- rnorm(50)
y <- rnorm(x)

Generate two pseudo-random normal vectors of x- and y-coordinates.
```

The documentation says the (first and only non-optional) parameter to `rnorm` is the length of the result vector. So `x <- rnorm(50)` produces a vector of 50 random values from a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 1.

So far so good. But why does `rnorm(x)` seem to do what `y <- rnorm(50)` or `y <- rnorm(length(x))` would have done? Either of these alternatives seem clearer to me.

My guess as to what happens is this:

1. The wrapper for `rnorm` didn’t care what kind of thing `x` is and just passed to the underlying C function a pointer to the C `struct` for `x` as an R object.
2. R objects represented in C are structs followed by “data”; the data of the C representation of an R vector of reals starts with two integers, the first of which is the vector's length. (The vector elements follow those integers.) I found this out by reading up on R internals [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#SEXPTYPEs).
3. If a C function were written to find the value of an R integer from a passed pointer-to-R-object, and it were called with a pointer to an R vector of reals, it would find the vector’s length in the place it would look for the single integer.

In addition to my main question of “How can I figure out something like this more easily?”, I wouldn’t mind knowing whether what I think is going on is correct and whether the fact that `rnorm(x)` is idiomatic R in this context or more of a sloppy choice. Given that it does something useful, can it be relied upon or is it just lucky behavior for an expression that isn’t well-defined in R?

I’m used to strongly-typed languages like C or SQL, which have easier-to-follow (for me) semantics and which also have more comprehensive references available, so any references for R that have a programming-language-theory focus or are aimed at people used to strong typing would be good, too.

Comment: You can find help for functions with a function name or character string of the function name, e.g., `help(rnorm)` or `help("rnorm")` (or the shortcut `?rnorm`). If you look at `help(help)`, the not-strongly-typedness of its first argument is also documented ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is documented behavior. From `?rnorm`:

> Usage: [...]
>
> ```
>  rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
> ```
>
> Arguments:
>   [...]
>
> ```
>    n: number of observations. If ‘length(n) > 1’, the length is
>       taken to be the number required.
> ```

Comment: Well, how about that. I thought I looked at `?rnorm` but my bad for probably having gotten frustrated too soon after just googling “rnorm” and not finding that detail. Thanks for the excellent, if a little embarrassing, answer!